# Arm template: concatenate each element of an array with constant value

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

When creating an arm template is it possible to concatenate each element of an array with a constant string? Below is my created parameter and the resource I am trying to create.

```
  "parameters": {

    "servicesNames": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        "test-api-content",
        "test-svc-content"
      ]
    }
  }

    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('servicesNames'),'pip')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "PIPaddresscopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('servicesNames'))]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "PublicIPAddress"
      }
   }
```

I would like the output of the resource name to be created with

> "test-api-contentpip"

How ever I am getting the following error

> The provided parameters for language function 'concat' are invalid.
>   Either all or none of the parameters must be an array

Please suggest how I can concatenate each value of the element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add to existing answer (as it is a bit unclear in my opinion).

What you are trying to do with your code - concatenate array with a string, and what you need to do is concatenate each element of the array with string.

There's a `copyIndex()` function that represent current iteration of the loop. and you can use `array[number]` to access specific member of the array. so

```
parameters('servicesNames')[copyIndex()]
```

means `parameters('servicesNames')[0]` and `parameters('servicesNames')[1]` in your case. That would effectively mean you've iterated over this array.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate each value of the element by modifying your **name** property for your **publicIpAddress** resource as below.

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('servicesNames')[copyIndex()], 'pip')]",
```

**[copyIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-numeric#copyindex):**

This function is always used with a copy object.

If no value is provided for offset, the current iteration value is returned. The iteration value starts at zero.